# node.js / axios AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE with PayPal Subscriptions API

Tags: paypal, axios, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to activate a PayPal subscription since the `NODE SDK` doesn't support the subscription activation. For doing so I've created this method that generate a `PayPal` access token:

```
let getAccessToken = async () => {
    return await axios(options).then((response) => {
        return response.data.access_token
    });
}
```

the options contains the following details:

```
const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    },
    data: qs.stringify(data),
    auth: {
        username: PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
        password: PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET
    },
    url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token'
}
```

this working fine but I'm having some problems activating the subscription, this is the method that handle this:

```
let activateSubscription = async (accessToken, subscriptionId) => {

    return await axios.post(
        `${baseURL}/v1/billing/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/activate`,
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((data) => {
            return true;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response.data);
            return false;
        });
}
```

Essentially I pass the generated `accessToken` and the `subscriptionId`, but I get as response this:

```
{
  name: 'AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE',
  message: 'Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.',
  links: [
    {
      href: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error',
      rel: 'information_link'
    }
  ]
}
```

My suspicion was that the generated token was incorrect, so I tried it in postman sending this request:

```
{{host}}/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-7D10FGKVNMD0/activate
```

and the returned content is `204` which is okay according to what doc says [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_activate).

The request seems correct, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What baseURL are you sending it to and what HTTP headers are you getting back

Comment: Also how did you obtain `I-7D10FGKVNMD0` to begin with? If it was from a smart payment button with normal creation settings it will already be active

Comment: @PrestonPHX You can see the full response here: https://pastebin.com/325HgQwM there is the `baseUrl` too which is this: `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-FLXLWEUS2UXD/activate`

Comment: @PrestonPHX Smart Payment Buttons automatically activate a subscription, but I set `user_action: "CONTINUE",` in the `application_context`, 'cause I need to perform some extra checking in my server side. So the subscription status is `APPROVED`. The subscription ref `I-7D10FGKVNMD0` is returned by the `createSubscription` method available in the Smart Payment Buttons: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#4-create-a-subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the headers wrong. From the pastebin:

`data: '{"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer A21AAEj_0lJjny7Hc1aL7l5irIxOqOjyW_pSfT2WC9APAQFXHTYzKL0womW1mZvS6mKWsWMytMc6H6NIMPMnOK7zhzHKHsSAw","Content-Type":"application/json"}}',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2',
      'Content-Length': 170
    },`

So, PayPal isn't actually getting your Authorization header

Comment: I'm doing the same for `getAccessToken` function, `axios` accept the `headers` object, and I'm passing the same header. Which thing should I change in the `axios.post` function?

Comment: `.post(url, data, options)`, your options are getting sent as data

Comment: So I changed to: `axios.post(
        `${baseURL}/v1/billing/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/activate`,
        {},
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
            }
        }` but got: `The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.`

Comment: Is active, but I shouldn't get the error when activating it

Comment: That's right, you shouldn't. I wonder how it became mysteriously activated 8-)

Comment: According to the official documentation for the [PayPal Checkout Server Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/server-integration/), there is no mention of using or the setting of headers.

Comment: That document is for an old version of the PayPal Checkout, note `/archive/` in the URL.  Regardless, there are some required headers when using REST APIs. For the subscriptions as in this old question, you can see a curl example at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1

Comment: Current server integration documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls , and client side pattern to pair with those routes: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server